# Неправильно работает переход состояний в FSM aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Неправильно работает FSM: состояние меняется только при написании команды, которая запускает саму машину состояний, а остальные сообщения бот игнорирует. Также срабатывают не все команды в последнем хэндлере и машина состояний зависает. Чинится только перезапуском бота, в консоли ничего нет.

```
class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    upload_name = State()
    upload_description = State()
    upload_price = State()
    upload_photo = State()

async def upload(message : types.Message):
    await FSMAdmin.upload_name.set()
    await message.answer('Напиши название')

async def upload_name(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    await message.answer('Теперь отправь описание')
    await FSMAdmin.upload_description.set()

async def upload_description(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['description'] = message.text
    await message.answer('Теперь отправь цену')
    await FSMAdmin.upload_price.set()

async def upload_price(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['price'] = message.text
    await message.answer('Теперь отправь фото')
    await FSMAdmin.upload_photo.set()


async def upload_photo(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['photo'] = message.photo[0].file_id
        await message.answer('Готово!'))
    await state.finish()


def register_admin_handlers(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(upload, commands=['up'], state=None, is_chat_admin=True)
    dp.register_message_handler(upload_name, state=FSMAdmin.upload_name)
    dp.register_message_handler(upload_description, state = FSMAdmin.upload_description)
    dp.register_message_handler(upload_price, state=FSMAdmin.upload_price)
    dp.register_message_handler(upload_photo, content_types=['photo'], state=FSMAdmin.upload_photo)
```

[image: Пример работы]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import logging

import aiogram.utils.markdown as md
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils import executor


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

API_TOKEN = 'Token'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)

storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    upload_name = State()
    upload_description = State()
    upload_price = State()
    upload_photo = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands='up')
async def upload(message : types.Message):
    await FSMAdmin.upload_name.set()
    await message.answer('Напиши название')

@dp.message_handler(state = FSMAdmin.upload_name)
async def upload_name(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await message.answer('Теперь отправь описание')    

@dp.message_handler(state = FSMAdmin.upload_description)
async def upload_description(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['description'] = message.text
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await message.answer('Теперь отправь цену')
    
@dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.upload_price)
async def upload_price(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['price'] = message.text
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await message.answer('Теперь отправь фото')
    

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=FSMAdmin.upload_photo)
async def upload_photo(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['photo'] = message.photo[0].file_id        
    await bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            md.text(
                md.text('Name: ', md.bold(data['name'])),
                md.text('Description: ', md.code(data['description'])),
                md.text('Price :', data['price']),
                md.text('Photo id ', data['photo'])                
            ),           
            parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN,
        )
    await message.answer('Готово!')
    await state.finish() 
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Сделал так как привык.

Comment: Сделал так, как вы сказали, но бот все так же не реагирует ни на что кроме двух команд - /up и /cancel, причем обе эти команды дают одинаковый результат - переход к следующему состоянию, вместо прерывания работы по команде /cancel.

Comment: Изменил ответ. Все работает

Comment: Спасибо, вроде заработало